# Lagrange multiplier problem with two constraints

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Can someone please verify an answer for me for the following Lagrange multiplier problem?

> Consider the function in three variables defined by
>
> $$ f(x,y,z) = xy + yz$$
>
> and subject to the constraints 
>   \begin{align} x + 2y - 6 &= 0, \\ x - 3z &= 0. \end{align}
>
> Find the critical point for the constrained problem using Lagrange
>   multiplier method.

Would really appreciate if someone can just post the answer for this.

I really need to verify my answer.

Comment: How about, instead, you post your answer and we'll tell you if it's correct and, if not, where you made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: consider the  function
$$L(x,y,z,\alpha,\beta)=xy+yz+\alpha(x+2y-6)+\beta(x-3z)$$
we get by differentiating
$$f_x=y+\alpha+\beta=0$$
$$f_y=x+z+2\alpha=0$$
$$f_z=y-3\beta=0$$
$$f_{\alpha}=x+2y-6=0$$
$$f_{\beta}=x-3z=0$$
and we get $$\alpha=-2,\beta=\frac{1}{2},x=3,y=\frac{3}{2},z=1$$

Comment: @user263516 You can also solve the problem with replacing the constraints in your function if you don't want to work with Lagrangian but the method with Lagrangian is more safe in order to not make some calculation mistakes.